# JQuery Fade-In function doesn't seem to get called

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a question about a function that I am writing with Jquery posted below. The first function works fine. When the page loads, Jquery make a sidenav div fadeout in a few seconds to display:none. The div to the right of it will slide left. The changing of the background to red is just some testing, however, it all works perfectly.

The second function is a clickable event...that is supposed to return the sliding div back to it's original position. Which it does. But then it is supposed to fade in, the div that was faded out OnpageLoad. This part does not work. The div stays hidden. Can anyone help me with this? I just need the #sidenav-cont div to fade back into view after the other div has slid back into place.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#sidenav-cont").delay(2000).fadeToggle(3000).queue(function() {
     $(".colleft").show("slow").delay(100).animate({right:'+=350'},2000).queue(function() {
       $(this).css('background-color','red').stop(true, true);
     });
   });
 });


 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("a.open").click(function () {
     $(".colleft").show("slow").animate({left:'+=350'},2000).queue(function() {
       $("#sidenav-cont").fadeToggle(3000);
     });
   });
 });
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.  It makes it much easier to read.

Comment: could you please add your jquery, css and html to http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your callbacks do not call [dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) or the `next` function provided as an argument by [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/#queue2) before returning. Failing to do that effectively locks the queue and would explain why the callback in the second part of your code is never called.

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sidenav-cont").delay(2000).fadeToggle(3000)
                      .queue(function(next) {
        $(".colleft").show("slow").delay(100).animate({right:'+=350'},2000)
                     .queue(function(next) {
            $(this).css('background-color','red').stop(true, true);
            next();
        });
        next();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.open").click(function () {
        $(".colleft").show("slow").animate({left:'+=350'},2000)
                     .queue(function(next) {
           $("#sidenav-cont").fadeToggle(3000);
           next();
        });
    });
});
```